# Aerogear - How to send data in push notification from Java to Web

Tags: javascript, java, web, service-worker, aerogear

I am implementing web push notification using Aerogear JS Cookbook's Chrome Push API with AeroGear Unified Push Demo. In that after implementing I am getting the notification but only with static data. I don't know how should pass actual dynamic data in notification.
Can anyone explain how can i achieve it.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am facing the same problem, I am only receiving a null message, you have to implement an API in order to get the message on the website.
Although, I found two issues created by jboss on Aug 2018 (https://issues.jboss.org/browse/AEROGEAR-7861 and https://issues.jboss.org/browse/AEROGEAR-7862. 
It seems that in a near future we will have the variant Push Notifications to Web working on UPS with a message. 
As you can see on github they were testing issue 7861, although it was rejected (https://github.com/aerogear/aerogear-unifiedpush-server/pull/1007)

Comment: Thanks for replying but I have used firebase and implemented web push notification successfully.

Comment: What have you done diferent from Aerogear JS Cookbook's Chrome Push API with AeroGear Unified Push Demo?